# Get the ID of WordPress posts with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a script where I need to get the IDs of posts:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
   $('#myCustomButton').click(function() {
      var attachementId = xxx;
   });
});
```

Where the "xxx" is I need the ID of the current Post-ID. Any Idea how to get that with JS? With PHP I can do this:

```
'postID' => $post->ID
```

Comment: Bind your Post-ID on  `myCustomButton` using data attribute. On click get your data attribute like `$(this).data("id")` .

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {    
   $('#myCustomButton').click(function() {
      var attachementId = <?php echo $post->ID ?>;
   });
});
```